# Plotly assigning colors based on label

Tags: r, colors, label, plotly

I'm sure there's a really easy way to do this but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I'm doing a scatter graph in Plot_ly.
Each point that I'm plotting has been assigned a label e.g. Pass, High, Low, Sigma high etc...

[image]

My problem is that I can't seem to fix what color plot_ly assigns to each label.
I want Pass to always be White, High to always be Green and so on, but it seems to randomly assign colors each time.

Here is the code I'm using to plot

```
      library("plotly")
      p <- plot_ly(PT, 
             type='scatter', 
             x=XAVG, 
             y=YAVG, 
             mode= "markers",
             marker=list(size=3,bgcolor="#e5e5e5"),
             color = label,
             colors=c("yellow","red","cyan","magenta",'blue',"green3","white"),

             zeroline=F,
             text=paste("MEAS = ",PT$MEAS,"Head_ID = ",substr(PT$SHD_ID,2,5)))
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I've been stuck on this for ages!

Thanks!

Comment: What package contains plot_ly? Couldn't find it.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal dataset to reproduce? E.g. the objects PT, XAVB, YAVB. Also, add the information of the package you are using ("plotly") please..

Comment: as @Arcoutte suggested, please share your data. You can use dput() on your data set instead of posting an image of the data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You describe `label` in your post but `label` is missing from your data so I've added a `label` column to `PT` with some labels corresponding to colours as seem to be suggested in  your comments.  `PT` is now:

```
  SHD_ID       MEAS     XAVG    YAVG PPKLOW PPKUP PKSLOW PKSUP colour label
1  1L3P1   0.300018  -5774.5 94350.5  FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE   blue  Fail
2  1LSP0   0.300018  14245.5 94350.5  FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE   blue  Fail
3  1L802 600.000000 -25024.5 94350.5  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE green3  Mean
4  ILSOl   0.300018  -5004.5 94350.5  FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE   blue  Fail
5  1LSOO   0.300018  15015.5 94350.5  FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE   blue  Fail
6  1LSN2 600.000000 -24254.5 94350.5  FALSE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE green3  Mean
```

The code first creates `color_map` as a vector with named components to define the mapping between your labels and your colors.  It then creates the plot assigning colors to the `marker` property `color` based on `color_map` and `label`. The `label` values are also used to create a `group` so that the assignment of color to labels is shown in the legend. I've made the markers larger just so the colors are easier to see.

```
#
# create a map between colors and labels  
# colors ending in numbers are not recognized by plot_ly
#  
  color_map <- c(Pass="yellow", High="red", Low= "cyan",
                 Sigma= "magenta", Mean='limegreen', Fail="blue", Median="violet")
#
# plot points using color_map to assign colors by label
#      show label colors in legend
#
  p <- plot_ly(PT, 
               type='scatter', 
               x=XAVG, 
               y=YAVG, 
               mode= "markers",
               marker=list(size=10, bgcolor="#e5e5e5", 
                              color=color_map[label]),
               group = label,
               zeroline=FALSE,
               text=paste("MEAS = ", MEAS,"Head_ID = ",substr(SHD_ID,2,5)))
```

Comment: @WaltS if i would like to specify a particular color to only Pass, High and Low as "Black" and for rest may vary different colors...... then how to specify ??..... thanks in advance