# Python - plotly assigning scatterplot colors by label

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to replicate [one of the basic examples in Plotly R](https://plot.ly/r/line-and-scatter/#qualitative-colorscales) into Plotly Python, but finding it impossible.

The same problem is also solved in R here:
[Plotly assigning colors based on label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655118/plotly-assigning-colors-based-on-label)

```py
trace0 = go.Scatter( x = x1, y = y1, mode = 'markers',
                    name = ytitle +  ' X vs ' + Atitle, 
                    marker=dict(size=4, symbol='circle', 
                                color=colorsIdx, colorbar= go.ColorBar(title= 'colorbar'),
                            colorscale='Viridis')
                    )
```

The closest I've gotten is using a colorbar, but that is suboptimal since I can't figure out how to pick colors so that they don't blend together, and then the color legend makes the graph look like there's some continuous data going on which is not the case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a dictionary and map the colors accordingly:

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

d  = {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [3, 4, 5], 'z': ['A', 'B', 'A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

colorsIdx = {'A': 'rgb(215,48,39)', 'B': 'rgb(215,148,39)'}
cols      = df['z'].map(colorsIdx)

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = df.x,
    y = df.y,
    mode = 'markers',
    marker=dict(size=15, color=cols)
)

data = [trace]
py.iplot(data)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know about this. I have a pandas dataframe with a dozen different levels. Do I really need to set the color manually for each level?

Comment: @mic colorsidx is a dict, so you could create a dictionary comprehension and assign colors with the random() function or range(). This would iterate through the available labels and assign a color sequentially or at random. idea in brief: `{i:k for i in df.columns for k in range(len(df.columns))}`

Comment: @Info5ek Doh! You are right, I keep forgetting about comprehensions... Thanks!

Comment: I ended up here because I was working on a similar problem. I share my code below which is able to randomly generate N colors, and then assign them to your P categories by using dict comprehension https://github.com/PortWhisperer/MachineLearningStudies/blob/f3c10a4011f1c3fa5effd1d5836e4d928b643066/src/HW2NO4.py#L124-L136